# Prove that the inclusion $i : A \rightarrow X$ is a continuous function, provided that $A$ has the subspace topology

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

*Prove that the inclusion $i : A \rightarrow X$ is a continuous function, provided that $A$ has the subspace topology*

i.e. $A$ has the subspace topology $\implies$ $i : A \rightarrow X$ is a continuous function

Topology on $X$ is given by $(X, \tau)$, and the topology on $A$ is $(A, \tau_A)$ with subspace topology, $\tau_A=${$U  \cap A: U \in \tau$}

A continuous function maps open sets to open sets so I think a proof can utilise this year, but I cannot explicitly come up with open sets myself

Would very much appreciate your help, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A continuous function has open inverse images for open sets. They don't have to map open sets to open sets.

Hint: $i^{-1}[U] = U \cap A$.